# fetching value from database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

This is the data am having in my table named rent

```
    id    date     stud_id  paid    balance

    18  10-2016       94    15000   15000
    19  10-2016       94    10000   5000
    20  10-2016       96    25000   5000
    21  10-2016       96    5000    0
```

here i want to get last inserted stud_id balance but am getting the first one.
my code looks like this

```
public function rent_outstanding($hos,$dt)
{
    $this->db->select('student_hostel.*,rent.balance,rent.paid');
    $this->db->join('rent','rent.stud_id=student_hostel.id');
    $this->db->where('status!=','G');
    $this->db->where('status!=','R');
    $this->db->where('hostel',$hos);
    $this->db->where('rent.date',$dt);
    $this->db->select_sum('paid');
    $this->db->group_by('stud_id');
    $query=$this->db->get('student_hostel');
    return $query;
}
```

my student_hostel table looks like this

```
     id   first_name  last_name    stud_id     admit_date   hostel   class  room bed status

     94     ss        ff          PHBH00094     01-10-2016   12        16   115  501A    P
     96    maltu      uv          PHBH00096     01-10-2016   12        16   115  501C    p
```

am getting my result like this

```
SI.No   STUDENT ID   NAME    RENT    PAID    BALANCE
 1      PHBH00094     Ss    30000   25000    15000  
 2      PHBH00096    Maltu  30000   30000    5000
```

i want to get my result like this

```
SI.No   STUDENT ID   NAME    RENT    PAID    BALANCE
 1      PHBH00094     Ss    30000   25000    5000   
 2      PHBH00096    Maltu  30000   30000    0
```

Comment: anybody have any idea

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify somewhere to take the max of ID from rent table.
This query should give you that.

```
select stud_id ,first_name, paid, balance from rent rt, student_hostel s where
hostel='$hosr' and ent.date='$dt' and id = (select max(id) from rent r where r.stud_id = rt.stud_id) and status!= 'G' and status!= 'R'
```

Add date to inner query if you need balance of that date `id = (select max(id) from rent r where r.stud_id = rt.stud_id and r.date='$dt')`

For Codeignitor you can write the query directly:

```
    $sql = "select stud_id ,first_name, paid, balance from rent rt, student_hostel s where hostel=? and ent.date=? and id = (select max(id) from rent r where r.stud_id = rt.stud_id) and status!= 'G' and status!= 'R'";

    $this->db->query($sql, array($hosr, $dt));
```

More info here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#query-bindings

Comment: i have a doubt whether can write this according to my model

Comment: @MOHAMMED Updated.

Comment: i mean values under paid columns